# Nested LINQ returning a this method cannot be translated into a store expression exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

The following LINQ:

```
retval = ( from jm in entities.JobMasters
                 where jm.UserId == userId && jm.IsRemote == false
                 select new JobDto
                 {
                     JobMasterId = jm.JobMasterId,
                     ExternalTaskId = jm.ExternalTaskId,
                     JobDetails = ( from jd in entities.JobDetails
                                    where jd.JobMasterId == jm.JobMasterId
                                    select new JobDetailDto { ScreenFieldId = jd.ScreenFieldId, FieldValue = jd.FieldValue }
                     ).ToList()
                 }
            ).ToList();
```

is giving me this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KernWcfTest.DataTransferObjects.JobDetailDto] 
>   ToList[JobDetailDto](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[KernWcfTest.DataTransferObjects.JobDetailDto])' method, 
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here are the two dto classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class JobDetailDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ScreenFieldId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(JobDetailDto))]
public class JobDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int JobMasterId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ExternalTaskId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<JobDetailDto> JobDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the sub-select and the JobDetails list. I tried adding the KnownType but it didn't work.

This all works fine in LINQ Pad.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call ToList on the inner query (the one for JobDetails). The error is "This .ToList method you speak of -- it can't be translated to T-SQL!"

This should work:

```
retval = ( from jm in entities.JobMasters
             where jm.UserId == userId && jm.IsRemote == false
             select new JobDto
             {
                 JobMasterId = jm.JobMasterId,
                 ExternalTaskId = jm.ExternalTaskId,
                 JobDetails =   from jd in entities.JobDetails
                                where jd.JobMasterId == jm.JobMasterId
                                select new JobDetailDto { ScreenFieldId = jd.ScreenFieldId, FieldValue = jd.FieldValue }
                 )
             }
        ).ToList();
```

Note that you can call ToList on the end of the query, as that part doesn't need to be translated to T-SQL.

Comment: I think you are heading in the right direction, but that gives me Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<KernWcfTest.DataTransferObjects.JobDetailDto>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<KernWcfTest.DataTransferObjects.JobDetailDto>'.

Comment: What error do you get (if any) if you change the last .ToList() to .AsEnumerable().ToList()?

Comment: The problem now is that your DTO doesn't map well to your queries. Let your DTO accept an IEnumerable<T>, or do separate queries.

Comment: Changed DTO to accept IEmumerable<T> and all now works. Thanks Judah.

Comment: Martin - tried your suggestion but didn't work. Same error as in original question.