# How to correctly convert from IEnumerable<T> to List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have this LINQ

```
 var questions = _context.Questions
            .Where(q => q.Level.Level == level)
            .Select(q => new QuestionViewModel
            {
                Text = q.Text,
                Id = q.Id,
                IsMultiSelected = q.IsMultiSelected,
                AnswerViewModels = q.Answers
                                       .Select(
                                           a => new AnswerViewModel
                                                    {
                                                        Checked = false,
                                                        Text = a.Text,
                                                        Id = a.Id
                                                    }) as List<AnswerViewModel>
            });
        return questions.ToList();
```

I get

```
Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1' and a check of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.
```

in

```
return questions.ToList();
```

I don't use anonymous types in select. How to resolve this error ?

## UPDATE

I coded some solution

```
    List<QuestionViewModel> result = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
    var questions = from q in _context.Questions
                    where q.Level.Level == level
                    select new QuestionViewModel()
                               {
                                   Text = q.Text,
                                   Id = q.Id,
                                   IsMultiSelected = q.IsMultiSelected,
                                   AnswerViewModels = from a in q.Answers
                                                      select new AnswerViewModel
                                                                 {
                                                                     Text = a.Text,
                                                                     Id = a.Id,
                                                                     Checked = false
                                                                 }
                               };
    var qList = questions.ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < questions.Count(); i++)
    {
        var q = qList[i]; //question
        var a = q.AnswerViewModels.ToList(); //answers for question
        var answers = new List<AnswerViewModel>(); //List answers
        for(int j = 0; j < a.Count(); j++)
        {
            //add new Answer from IEnumerable<AnswerViewQuestion> to List<...>
            answers.Add(new AnswerViewModel
                            {
                                Checked = false,
                                Id = a[j].Id,
                                Text = a[j].Text
                            });
        }
        result.Add(q);
    }
```

How to optimize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var questions = _context.Questions
            .Where(q => q.Level.Level == level)
            .Select(q => new QuestionViewModel
            {
                Text = q.Text,
                Id = q.Id,
                IsMultiSelected = q.IsMultiSelected,
                AnswerViewModels = q.Answers
                                       .Select(
                                           a => new AnswerViewModel
                                                    {
                                                        Checked = false,
                                                        Text = a.Text,
                                                        Id = a.Id
                                                    })
            }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new QuestionViewModel
              {
                   Text = x.Text,
                   Id = x.Id,
                   IsMultiSelected = x.IsMultiSelected,
                   AnswerViewModels = x.Answers.ToList()
               });
        return questions.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with

```
.Select(a => new AnswerViewModel { ... }) as List<AnswerViewModel>
```

It should be

```
.Select(a => new AnswerViewModel { ... }).ToList()
```

The reason is that the correct way to convert a LINQ-generated `IEnumerable` to a `List` is of course by calling the `ToList` extension method, which you are already doing in the last line given.

Comment: just to clarify, if you use Jon's proposal, you need to return just questions: 
return question;

Comment: Dont't work. 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExpertApplication.ViewModels.AnswerViewModel] ToList[AnswerViewModel](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ExpertApplication.ViewModels.AnswerViewModel])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. '

Comment: I search some question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800834/nested-linq-returning-a-this-method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression' but it's answers not work for me